# Window.open works only first time, otherwise blank page

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open a up an URL in new tab like this:
`window.open('adl:\\restofurl', '_blank')`

This works well for the first time: Popup is blocked and asks me if I want to open up the url. However when I add an exception for the pop ups to the site, the second time window.open is called, chrome only opens up a blank page. (also does not work for firefox)

When I try 
`window.open('http:\\restofurl','_blank')`
chrome always opens it correctly.
It looks as it has problem with the "adl" part, but I don't know why.
Does anyone has a similar problem?

**EDIT :**

I am trying to do this on android device, where is an app that starts after you go to this url. However the behaviour is the same also for not mobile devices

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Anyone else not heard of `adl` protocol before?

Comment: I am trying to do this on android device, where is an app that starts after you go to this url. However the behaviour is the same also for not mobile devices, so I ommited the information to simplify description.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Mozilla Developer Network [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), it is best to use the full URL of what you're trying to open.

> The `open()` method creates a new secondary browser window, similar to
>   choosing New Window from the File menu. The strUrl parameter specifies
>   the URL to be fetched and loaded in the new window. **If strUrl is an
>   empty string, then a new blank, empty window (URL about:blank) is
>   created with the default toolbars of the main window.**
>
> Note that remote URLs won't load immediately. When window.open()
>   returns, the window always contains about:blank. The actual fetching
>   of the URL is deferred and starts after the current script block
>   finishes executing. The window creation and the loading of the
>   referenced resource are done asynchronously.

In your case `adl:\\restofurl` is not recognized as a legitimate URL by the browser. That's where it creates a blank window and you get the correct output when you use `http:\\restofurl` as the URL to open.

also I'd advise you to use absolute path of the document to open.

Comment: what about the first time?

Comment: Could be something happens with regards to the protocol('adl:\\') you use. Some popup blockers automatically blocks unknown protocols hence use absolute path of the document you want to open.

Comment: I don't want to open a document (I edited the question, sorry for missing info).. However what I find weird, is that the first time it is - blocked -> enabled -> recognized -> and the url is opened up correctly.

Comment: @user3737648 what do you mean by `adl:\\` since i'm not familiarize with it.

Comment: That is just some custom thing, and there is android app, that opens up, after the url is opened. The problem is probably that it is not recognized (as mentioned).. however it is weird, that it opens up ok when the popups are blocked.